# Declare a generic Typescript array with a common base interface as types

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'd like to declare an Array of items with a common base interface, but can't figure out how.

I have a base interface and several child interfaces extending the base:

```
interface Animal {
  name: string;
  birthdate: Date;
}

interface Bird extends Animal {
  featherColor: string;
}

interface Dog extends Animal {
  furColor: string;
}
```

I would like to do something like this:

```
interface AnimalList {
  animals: Array<? extends Animal>
}

// define an example
const list: AnimalList = {
  animals: [
    {name: 'Bobby', birthdate: new Date(), furColor: 'brown'},
    {name: 'Bobby', birthdate: new Date(), featherColor: 'green'},
  ]
}
```

How can I declare an array like that? Please note: I cannot use classes as the definition of the interfaces will be done with an OpenApi generator.

I tried `Animal[]`, but that will produce:

```
TS2322: Type '{ name: string; birthdate: Date; furColor: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Animal'. 
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'furColor' does not exist in type 'Animal'.
```

Comment: That was my first approach, yes. But that will produce an `TS2322: Type '{ name: string; birthdate: Date; furColor: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Animal'.   Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'furColor' does not exist in type 'Animal'.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

```js
interface Animal {
    name: string;
    birthdate: Date;
}

interface Bird extends Animal {
    featherColor: string;
}

interface Dog extends Animal {
    furColor: string;
}

interface AnimalList<T extends Animal> {
    animals: Array<T>
}


const list = <T extends Animal>(arg: AnimalList<T>) => arg

/**
 * Fisrt, accepts all types which extends Animal
 */
const result = list({
    animals: [
        { name: 'Bobby', birthdate: new Date(), furColor: 'brown' },
        { name: 'Bobby', birthdate: new Date(), featherColor: 'green' },
    ]
})


/**
 * Second, if you want to define upfront allowed types
 */
const list2: AnimalList<Bird | Dog> = {
    animals: [
        { name: 'Bobby', birthdate: new Date(), furColor: 'brown' },
        { name: 'Bobby', birthdate: new Date(), featherColor: 'green' },
    ]
}
```

As you see, you may use function in order to infer the type and you can use union type

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIImAWzgG2QbwChkTkQ5MIAuZAZzClAHMBuY0gI2CjAAsATOJBoARIRDYBfQoVCRYiFACFu-ZBAAekEP1poM2PEVLIYEIb2gBhAPY4bUGvUYhWhabPDR4SZCJtM6loQOnroWLgE7CQwAK5QtvaOdAzMUjJy3or6ETgAMsD0ADwAKkHaujmGAHxRJnAGuLQ0qFBQcACepdXuMoQINiD0yDiFYMgAvMil5SGV4TUAFHBQTC2N%20WPdAJSTtStMMgD0AFQnxCfIAGKFPBdH-YPDUBC0sTjjU6P0i8akDblmsgANrREwEMgUajIADkShsHA4HRhABpkFweAJxDQQBAAO5%20cSLbZouIJOwOGgwjhQGx4kAw5CSFFgkz4SGUKnwxHItEYviCYRkfGEyDE0nmPjWCnJGFMF4hRnMsEAXXc2z6p3OyEuAGUIAMdPdHkNxt8wAAmda5ArFFRQNQAHz8AVqUz%20JABhiBoPBpHZ5E5sO5SNR6O4AuxwoJYjFJNM8USlNhNLpDKZLL9JADUK5CNDfIjWKFuJjRPjZgs0qSVPlEEVGdVvSAA)

**UPDATE**

As for second approach

As you might have noticed, you are unable to add animal which is neither Bird nor Dog

```js
const list2: AnimalList<Bird | Dog> = {
    animals: [
        { name: 'Bobby', birthdate: new Date(), furColor: 'brown' },
        { name: 'Bobby', birthdate: new Date(), featherColor: 'green' },
        { name: 'Bobby', birthdate: new Date(), fname: 'green' }, // error
    ]
}
```

If you want to filter birds from the array, you can use typeguards:

```js
const isBird = (animal: Animal): animal is Bird =>
    Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(animal, 'featherColor')

const getAnimals = list2.animals.filter(isBird) // Bird[]
```

It is not clear for me what you mean under

> regarding maintainability, bad habit, isn't it

Comment: The second approach is, regarding maintainability, bad habit, isn't it? It works indeed, but seems error prone if there are a lot of different interfaces and not like two or three. However, I don't understand what `list` does - it seems redundant?

Comment: @letmejustfixthat in this particular case `list` is redundant. I just wanted to show you different approaches.